# Error exit status 127 on installation of KDE desktop on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: installation, kde-plasma

I tried to install KDE desktop on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
At the end of installation, I got this error:

```
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/etc/environment: line 3: $: command not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--unpack):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

In other window message appear:

```
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My linux version is:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.16.0-77-generic (buildd@lgw01-09) 
(gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) ) 
#99~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 19:17:10 UTC 2016
```

Here some data about the machine:

```
ar-it07201                
description: Space-saving Computer
product: OptiPlex 9020 (OptiPlex 9020)
vendor: Dell Inc.
version: 01
serial: CRMVN22
width: 64 bits
```

An cpu procesor:

```
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 3a
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
      slot: SOCKET 0
      size: 3888MHz
      capacity: 3888MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz
      capabilities: x86-64 
    ....
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 3e
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 16GiB
```

Comment: It should be in https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: thanks, do you know if it is possible to move the question or to delete here and create there?